# Too big font size in table

Tags: tables, fontsize

I insert table into my text with the regular font size 12pt.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \small
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{tbl:my_label}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            asdasdasd                          & asdasdasd \\ \hline
            asdasdasd            & 2500     \\ \hline
        asdasdasd            & 97       \\ \hline
            asdasdasd & 1350     \\ \hline
            asdasdasd            & 25-30    \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}
```

After I insert this table font size increases up to kinda 18pt. So it's really enormous and how can I fix it?
It's a problem var:
[image]

And what I expect:
[image]

It's just for example and I understand table be more narrow.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\resizebox` for tabulars – it yields inconsistent fonnt sizes. What are you trying to do with this command?

Comment: So could you explain how to fit wide table into textwidth?

Comment: Does it require a single page, or will it split over pages?

Comment: whatever, it'll be nice if you explain the way for \longtable too.

Comment: To fits exactly the text width, the tool is `tabularx`. If the table has to split over pages, you have the `xltabular` environment, from the homonymous package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`, with the syntax of the former as to the caption, first head last foot, &c. Note that `tabularx` (and `xltabular`) requires at least one `X` column.

Comment: oh, I use it due to http://www.tablesgenerator.com designes tables this way.

Comment: If you have a two column table, it makes little sense to expand it to the text width: you'll end up with objects on the same row very far from each other and reading the table would become a pain.